# Xpath: Get value inside parentheses?

Tags: xpath

is it possible to directly scrape information inside parentheses with xpath? Or should I filter it later with regular expressions? This is what the HTML looks like:

`<span itemprop="title" class="active">Product name  (UN1QU3 C0D3)</span>`

With the following Xpath expression I can get everything inside this `<span>`:

`$xpath->query('//*[@id="crumbtrail"]/div[5]/span');`

Is it possible to directly get `UN1QU3 C0D3` by adjusting my query? Or should I use a regular expression on this later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substring-after` and `substring-before` to extract everything after `(` and before `)`:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//*[@id="crumbtrail"]/div[5]/span/text(), "("), ")")
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I don't really understand how to implement it. Should this replace my current expression?

Answer (score 1):

```
$xpath->query('//*[@id="crumbtrail"]/div[5]/span');
```

by using this query you will get span tag

```
$xpath->query('//*[@id="crumbtrail"]/div[5]/span/text()');
```

this query will be used to grab text from **span**

there is no way to filter parentheses data using Xpath for that you need to use regex or some string manipulations